# Drupal-Salesforce with NuSOAP

Tags: drupal, salesforce, nusoap

We have a Drupal 6 application (PHP 5) using the Salesforce module for integration. Everything works great on our current server, but we are moving to a server which does not allow the PHP SOAP extension, which the Salesforce module relies upon. NuSOAP does work on the new server.

From our initial effort, it's a very difficult task to patch the Salesforce module to use NuSOAP. Does anyone know of alternatives we can pursue, or perhaps provide assistance with the move to NuSOAP?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Zend SOAP client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html), I think that can work without the PHP extension as well.

In any case, I wouldn't touch NuSOAP with a ten foot array, it's very outdated. Latest release was in 2005.

Answer (score 2):

It seems eerie to read that, given the cost of going with Salesforce and integrating, you don't have enough control over your own server to enable the builtin SOAP extension.

As Mikl said, you can still use Zend SOAP in the Zend Framework, but being in PHP it cannot reach the performance of the builtin extension; and ZF still evolves rather fast, meaning a dependency which can be costly to maintain,  unlike the default SOAP extension.

And I would not want to use NuSOAP, due to its unmaintained state.

I think you really should reconsider your PHP configuration before continuing as you plan.